# Possible to exchange expired Microsoft Graph API access token for a new one?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am authenticating to the Graph API in my Startup.cs:

```
    app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
                new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    ClientId = appId,
                    Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0",
                    Scope = $"openid email profile offline_access {graphScopes}",
                    RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false // Setting this to true prevents logging in, and is only necessary on a multi-tenant app.
                    },
                    Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications 
                    {
                        AuthenticationFailed = OnAuthenticationFailedAsync,
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = async (context) =>
                        {
                            // This block executes once an auth code has been sent and received.
                            Evar idClient = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(appId)
                                .WithRedirectUri(redirectUri)
                                .WithClientSecret(appSecret)
                                .Build();

                            var signedInUser = new ClaimsPrincipal(context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity);
                            var tokenStore = new SessionTokenStore(idClient.UserTokenCache, HttpContext.Current, signedInUser);

                            string[] scopes = graphScopes.Split(' ');
                            var result = await idClient.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode(scopes, context.Code).ExecuteAsync();

                            var userDetails = await GraphUtility.GetUserDetailAsync(result.AccessToken);
```

After retrieving this access token, I store it into a class variable. The reason why I do this is so that I can retrieve it for use in one of my services (called by an API controller) that interfaces with the Graph API.

```
public GraphAPIServices(IDbContextFactory dbContextFactory) : base(dbContextFactory)
        {
            _accessToken = GraphUtility.GetGraphAPIAccessToken();

            _graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (requestMessage) =>
            {
                requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _accessToken);
            }));
        }
```

The problem that I am running into is that after some time, this access token eventually expires. I obviously can't run Startup.cs again so there is no opportunity to retrieve a new access token.

What I would like to know is if it's possible to exchange this expired access token for a new one without the need to request that the user logs in again with their credentials?

Comment: For your scenario, you should look for refresh token. Because when a client acquires an access token to access a protected resource (Graph), the client also receives a refresh token. The refresh token is used to obtain new access/refresh token pairs when the current access token expires. A refresh token is bound to a combination of user and client. A refresh token can be revoked at any time, and the token's validity is checked every time the token is used.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'm only getting an ID Token and an Access Token. There is no refresh token. I've added "offline_access" to my web app permission. I'm not entirely sure what else I could be missing.

Comment: Are you still looking for any help on this question?